# Is there any way to connect Arduino to the WSO2 platform?

Tags: arduino, wso2, amqp, mqtt, iot

I tried installing the WSO2 message broker, but from what I understand it only receive messages via AMQP protocol (not MQTT) and Arduino doesn't have a AMQP library.

How can I make Arduino send and receive messages from WSO2 Message Broker? Is there any way to receive MQTT messages with the message broker? Should I use another broker? Is there any AMQP library for Arduino?

Comment: Can you please more describe what do you want to achieve? Is your need bound particularly to WSO and MQTT?

Comment: @MichalFoksa It's only a preliminary study, i'm comparing the JBOSS platform and the WSO2 one. Now i'm trying to use the WSO2-MB 3.0 (in development) because this support the mqtt protocol and I can't find any amqp library for arduino to make it communicate with the wso2-mb 2.2.0. Any solution is accepted, my goal is to make Arduino and the WSO2 platform to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Message Broker 2.2.0 does not support MQTT protocol. But the upcoming version(3.0.0) will be supporting MQTT protocol.

You can try out the new pack at https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/MB/3.0.0/M6/wso2mb-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-m6.zip

Note : This is still under development.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make Arduino send and receive messages from WSO2 Message Broker?

Because you say "I'm new..." I will recommend that the advice of the hive mind is "don't" (or at least don't directly)

If you look at what is in contemporary use, consider that there is probably some good advice at the core of popular opinion.  MQTT, REST, COAP, XMPP are in use on microcontrollers because they are a good match for a highly resource constrained platform.  If nothing else, going along with the crowd will put you in good company of people who can help.

AMQP is promoted for enterprise applications and business to business, in other words big metal platforms.  If you look at some comparisons ([for example this AMQP overview](http://www.amqp.org/sites/amqp.org/files/2014.05.01%20ISO%2019464%20AMQP-ORG_0.pdf)) it is considered a feature increase above MQTT or HTTP.  Feature improvement means larger resource consumption.

*But I'm not saying don't do anything.*

My advice is to consider the approach of using a middle party.  For example, Node RED ([link to site](http://nodered.org/)) is meant for connecting various devices and also translating protocols.  Running Node RED on a tiny Linux box (for example Raspberry PI, or Intel NUC) is a way to connect little Arduino's pushing MQTT messages to bigger things.  A similar alternate is to use a web service as the middle ware.  For example Temboo is a service that want's to simplify connecting little Arduino's to the web ([link Temboo site](https://www.temboo.com/arduino)).  Note that I do see that neither of these support AMQP as of April 2015; that should be tell you something.